# Stability of an equilibrium point.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Let be

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \dot{x_1}=-ax_1^2+bx_1x_2+cx_2^2  \\
             \\ \dot{x_2}=-x_2+dx_1^2+mx_1x_2+nx_2^2             
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
a system; $a,b,c,d,m,n\in \mathbb{R}$ constants.

$1.$ If $a\neq0$ then $\bar{x}=0$ is inestable.

$2.$ If $a=0$ and $bd<0$ then $\bar{x}=0$ is asymptotically stable.

$3.$ If $a=0$ and $bd>0$ then $\bar{x}=0$ is unestable.

$4.$ If $a=b=0$ and $cd\ne0$ then $\bar{x}=0$ is unestable.

$5.$ If $a=b=c=0$ then $\bar{x}=0$ is stable but not asymptotically stable.

$6.$ If $a=d=0$ then $\bar{x}=0$ is stable but not asymptotically stable.

Let be $f_1(x_1, x_2)=-ax_1^2+bx_1x_2+cx_2^2$ and $f_2(x_1, x_2)=dx_1^2+mx_1x_2+nx_2^2.$ The idea is to find a function $\phi(x_1)$ such that $-\phi(x_1)+f_2(x_1, \phi(x_1))=0$ and $\phi(0)=0,\phi'(0)=0$ and apply the following result:

**Theorem:** Let's suppose that $f_1(x_1, \phi(x_1))=px_1^k+\Theta(|x_1|^{k+1})$ when $x_1\to 0$,$p\ne 0$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}.$

Then the equilibrium $\bar{x}=0$ of system is asymptotically stable if $p<0$ and $k$ odd and unstable otherwise.

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: @Rebellos I need to prove statements 1-5. The idea is to find the function $\phi(x_1)$ by Taylor expansion and identify $\Theta(|x_1|^{k+1}$

Comment: @MrYouMath I wouldn't say that all of these questions are totally different. All of them would be answered after finding center manifold of this system — it seems that this is the reason for introducing $\phi(x_1)$ although conditions for it are a bit strange to me.  Also you can't linearize in "easy case", but it's easy to get analytical solution in that case.

Comment: @Evgeny: You are right that linearization does not work in the easy case.

Comment: @Evgeny Linearization does not give an answer because it remains: $D_f(0,0)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0  & -1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Yeah, but you can solve this system of linear equations easily.

Comment: @Evgeny Yes, I already did $1-4$, but I'm missing the $5$ and the $6$. Could you help me solve these two?. For $5$ I have to prove that the equilibrium point $x_1=0$ of $\dot{x_1}=f_1(x_1,\phi(x_1))$ is stable but $f_1(x_1,x_2)=0$, ​​how would it do then? Thank you.

Comment: @MrYouMath What function of Liapunov helps me solve the $5.$ and the $6.$?

Comment: @Evgeny What is the center variety for?

Comment: There is a theorem: if you compute Jacobi matrix at equilibrium and all eigenvalues satisfy ${\rm Re} \; \lambda \leqslant 0$, then the stability of equilibrium only depends on center manifold. Center manifold is tangent to the subspace spanned by eigenspaces with ${\rm Re} \; \lambda = 0$.